# accept fails saying "too many open files" : but client again trying to reconnect within micro seconds

Tags: c, linux, sockets

May be very few learner got this kind of scenario. Actually what i am seeing in my client server application . Where client contact to server at each 5 seconds and asks for health of server machine(A typical socket communication in linux) . But in my case server is starving sometime for new file discripters and in this communication `Accept()` is failing saying  **too many open files** . Till now no problem because i can increase `nofile` limit. 
 
 But the problem is when there is such situation occurs `accept()` fail notification kept showing in logs by thousand times in a single second .
 SO my question is if i am asking to server after 5 second and once `accept()` fails then again it should be called at next iteration of my request ?  . Is my case is default behaviour of socket communication if yes then how i can restrict it to given interval .

Comment: Perhaps you need to start closing the file descriptors of previous connections, once you're done processing them....

Comment: Or maybe just keep the connection open rather than connecting every 5 seconds.  In any case a single `accept` failure shouldn't be flooding your logs but there isn't much anyone can say w/o the code in question.

Comment: I am closing them that is not the issue , Also i am trying make a sample code to reproduce it under my vision to see what is happning , will update code if i succeed

Comment: Continual open/close causing all available sockets to be stuck in TIME_WAIT?  Like @Duck says, stop doing all that open/close.